# How to use Collectors.collectingAndThen with Collectors.groupingBy

Tags: java, java-stream

Given the following list as example :

```
List<String> input = List.of("FOO", "FOO", "FOO", "FOO", "FOO", "BAR", "BAR", "BAZ", "BAZ", "BAZ", "DOO", "DOO");
```

I need to get the relative Frequency of each element and print it formatted as a string. To do so I have used 2 steps, first create a frequency map and then calculate relative percentage and format:

```
Map<String, Long> relativeFrequency =
        input.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()));

Map<String, String> relativeFrequency2 = relativeFrequency.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                entry -> String.format ( "%.02f%%", entry.getValue() * 100.  / input.size() )));

System.out.println(relativeFrequency2);
```

and get the result

```
{BAR=16.67%, DOO=16.67%, FOO=41.67%, BAZ=25.00%}
```

I was told to refactor the above and do it in one go using **Collectors.collectingAndThen**, but I can't seem to find the right syntax (compile error `Operator '*' cannot be applied to '<lambda parameter>', 'double'`). Can someone help to correct the following to get the same result as above?

```
Map<String, String> relativeFrequency3 = 
input.stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting(),
                total -> String.format ( "%.02f%%", total * 100.  / input.size() ))
));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were close.

```
List<String> input =
        List.of("FOO", "FOO", "FOO", "FOO", "FOO", "BAR",
                "BAR", "BAZ", "BAZ", "BAZ", "DOO", "DOO");
```

- the first argument to `collectingAndThen` would be `counting()` to get the frequency.
- then you process that frequency by converting it to a formatted percentage.

```
Map<String, String> map = input.stream().collect(Collectors
        .groupingBy(a -> a, Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.counting(),
                count -> "%.2f%%".formatted((double) count
                        / input.size() * 100))));
        
map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

printing each entry set yields

```
BAR=16.67%
DOO=16.67%
FOO=41.67%
BAZ=25.00%
```

Comment: May be worth to mention that `"%.2f%%".formatted()` is available for Java 13+ and already deprecated

Comment: Thanks.  Too bad it's deprecated as I actually like it.  Guess I'll have to revert to `String.format`.  it must be later than Java 17 since eclipse didn't flag it.

Comment: This seems to be a misunderstanding. This method was marked deprecated in JDK 13, because the possibility to mark an API as “Preview” feature did not exist yet. The method `formatted` was officially introduced in JDK 15 then. Compare with https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/12 “*Consequently, in Java SE 12 and 13, the APIs associated with preview features were terminally deprecated at birth, that is, annotated with @Deprecated(forRemoval=true, since=...) when they were introduced. … However, the deprecation-based approach was eventually dropped because it was confusing…*”

Comment: @Holger Well, I am still a tad confused.  So what is the verdict on `formatted`?

Comment: It was a preview feature in JDK 13 that was marked deprecated in the same version, as a bad attempt to mark preview features. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#formatted(java.lang.Object...)). Then, JDK 14 introduced real *Preview* features, so it was marked as such, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#formatted(java.lang.Object...)). Since JDK 15, it’s the real feature, you know of, and will stay as such (as far as we all know today). You can keep using it.

Comment: Ah.  A failed kludge to imply a `preview` annotation before `preview` existed.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.function.Function;

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        var input = List.of("FOO", "FOO", "FOO", "FOO", "FOO", "BAR", "BAR", "BAZ", "BAZ", "BAZ", "DOO", "DOO");
        var out = input.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                w -> w,
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.summingInt(w -> 1),
                    s -> String.format("%.02f%%", s * 100. / input.size()))
            ));
        System.out.println(out);
    }
}
```